# Adding general introduction to table of contents as chapter causes a problem

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I'm trying to add a general introduction to my report. Well I added it to the table of contents and without number. Using this code :

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Introduction générale}
\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\label{sec:IntroductionGénérale}
```

But the problem is :
I already added a mini table of contents in the begining of chapters.
So when I add the asterisk ,to hide the header the mini Table of contents disappears.
And when I delete it , I get a header in the general introduction.
This is the code I'm using :

```
    \documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumitem}%pou les puces
% the following is useful when we have the old nomencl.sty package
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%/usepackage{t1enc}% un second package
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
% un troisième package
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{lettrine} 

\floatstyle{boxed}
\title{Rapport de Projet De Fin D'Études}
\author{Amina GHABRI}
\usepackage{palatino}%police
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\normalfont\bfseries{--}}
}



\usepackage{babel}


\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\ }
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\ }

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}




%\usepackage{babel}

\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}




\makeatother

%\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}
\rmfamily
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{%
   \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0mm}%
      {-\baselineskip}%
      {.5\baselineskip}%
      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subparagraph{%
   \@startsection{subparagraph}{4}{0mm}%
      {-\baselineskip}%
      {.5\baselineskip}%
      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\dominitoc\tableofcontents{}\listoffigures

\listoftables


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Introduction générale}
\chapter{Introduction générale}
\label{sec:IntroductionGénérale}




Conçu originellement comme un système d’exploitation réservé pour les terminaux mobiles (Smartphones, Tablettes etc.), Android a bouleversé plusieurs domaines d’utilisation comme les téléviseurs, les autoradios et même les voitures. Il a changé automatiquement le fonctionnement  des entreprises et leurs environnements professionnels.








\chapter{Présenation du projet}
\label{sec:PrésenationDuProjet}







\minitoc \newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Introduction}% Add title to ToC
\section*{Introduction}
\label{sec:Introduction}

\lettrine[lines=2,loversize=0.08]{L}{}e succès retentissant des Smartphones sous Android a entrainé l'émergence quotidienne de nouvelles applications et services qui reposent sur la technologie Wi-Fi.
La première partie du chapitre est consacrée à la présentation du projet et à la spécification des besoins.
```

And this the result with * :

[image]

And this without * : the mini toc desapears :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `minitoc` package provides `\mtcaddchapter[...]` for addition of starred chapters to the ToC. This will maintain the ability for a `minitoc` as well -- see page 72 of the current `minitoc` documentation and make sure to use `\mtcaddchapter` **after** `\chapter*`!

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm,headheight=16pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumitem}%pou les puces
% the following is useful when we have the old nomencl.sty package
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%/usepackage{t1enc}% un second package
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
% un troisième package
%\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{lettrine} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\floatstyle{boxed}
\title{Rapport de Projet De Fin D'Études}
\author{Amina GHABRI}
\usepackage{palatino}%police
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\labelitemi{\normalfont\bfseries{--}}
}


\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\ }
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\ }

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}


\rmfamily

\makeatletter
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}

\renewcommand\paragraph{%
   \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0mm}%
      {-\baselineskip}%
      {.5\baselineskip}%
      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{%
   \@startsection{subparagraph}{4}{0mm}%
      {-\baselineskip}%
      {.5\baselineskip}%
      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\dominitoc
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\tableofcontents{}\listoffigures

\listoftables


\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\mtcaddchapter[Introduction générale]
\markboth{}{}
\minitoc
\label{sec:IntroductionGénérale}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\section{Some content in this starred chapter}

Conçu originellement comme un système d’exploitation réservé pour les terminaux mobiles (Smartphones, Tablettes etc.), Android a bouleversé plusieurs domaines d’utilisation comme les téléviseurs, les autoradios et même les voitures. Il a changé automatiquement le fonctionnement  des entreprises et leurs environnements professionnels.



\blindtext[5]



\counterwithin{section}{chapter}

\chapter{Présenation du projet}
\label{sec:PrésenationDuProjet}



\minitoc\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Introduction}% Add title to ToC
\section*{Introduction}
\label{sec:Introduction}

\lettrine[lines=2,loversize=0.08]{L}{}e succès retentissant des Smartphones sous Android a entrainé l'émergence quotidienne de nouvelles applications et services qui reposent sur la technologie Wi-Fi.
La première partie du chapitre est consacrée à la présentation du projet et à la spécification des besoins. 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well i solved the problem, i just changed in table of contents the chapter to a section :

```
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Introduction générale}
\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\label{sec:IntroductionGénérale}
```

Comment: You would actually need `\clearpage \addcontentsline{..}{..}{...} \chapter*{...} \label{..}`, otherwise you may end up writing an incorrect page to the ToC.